# How to find the prime between 1,000,000 and 1,000,020

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

This is a quiz from [Murderous maths](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Murderous-Maths-Box-Set/dp/140713194X), to find the (only) prime between 1,000,000 and 1,000,020.

Without a computer I could only get zoom down to
$1000003$,
$1000007$,
$1000009$, and
$1000019$.

Is there a way to find the prime without computer (and google)?

Comment: Two of these still have a factor $<50$. - Instead of finding factors, however, it may be easier to find $2^{p-1}\bmod p$?

Comment: With computer, the answer is $1000003$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry i don't get it... suppose p=47, how would $2^46\equiv 1 (mod 47)$ helps checking if any of the 4 numbers (1000003 , 1000007, 1000009, and 1000019) is a prime?

Comment: @athos:  cf. [Fermat primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I really don't think I'd enjoy computing $2^{1000002} \mod 1000003$ without a computer.

Comment: @RobertIsrael is right. I've looked into it, & powers get into the tens of thousands before the remainder is small. This isn't going to be one of those "this small power gets $7$ or something" jobs. There might, however, be nicer results with a base other than $2$.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, no base $<100$ looks useful.

Comment: $29|1000007$ and $47|1000019.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to have to undercut @HagenvonEitzen's suggestion. The least prime factors that refute the incorrect options are $29|10^6+7,\,293|10^6+9,\,47|10^6+19$. The middle one is especially laborious to find by hand. Without a computer, however, that's a *much* faster approach than using FLT with any small base.

Comment: so basically there's no shortcut for a primality test?